# Probability of rolling above a certain number with a die

Tags: probability

Kind of new to probability. This is a question pertaining to a game one of my classes is playing. If I am trying to roll an $8$ or above with a $10$-sided die, would it be better to roll twice with a $-2$ modifier, or once with a $-1$ modifier?

Comment: What exactly is a modifier? If you are using a $-1$ modifier and you roll a $9$, it is taken to be an $8$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the modifiers are substracted from any result rolled. You are trying to get at least an 8 (after the -2) with 2 rolls or to get at least an 8 (after the -1) with only 1 roll. Is that it?

In the first option, you are trying to get a 10 on at least 1 die, which is the opposite of not getting 10 on both dice. Therefore the probability is $1-\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2 = 19\%$

In the second option, you are trying to get a 9 or a 10, which is $\frac{2}{10} = 20\%$

The one-die-minus-one option is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your term "-k modifier" to mean if you roll $x$, $x-k$.

With a -2 modifier, you must roll a 10. This can happens exactly when you roll precisely one 10 (either on the first or second), or two 10s. These are disjoint events, so the probability of any of these happening is $9/100+9/100+1/100=19/100.$

With a -1 modifier, you must roll a 9 or 10 on one roll. Probability of this event is $2/10=20/100$.

So the -1 modifier is better.